# For an ArrayList<String> with long elements, how do you skip the first line?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of String where

System.out.println(Al.get(1))

```
AX225025 Equine influenza virus H3N8 // 8 (NS)
CAAAAGCAGGGTGACAAAAACATGATGGATTCCAACACTGTGTCAAGCTTTCAGGTAGACTGTTTTCTTT
GGCATGTCCGCAAACGATTTGCAGACCAAGAACTGGGTGATGCCCCATTCCTTGACCGGCTTCGCCGAGA
```

System.out.println(Al.get(2))

```
>LC335987 A/mute swan/Shimane/3211A001/2017 2017/11/05 8 (NS)
CCAGAAGTCCCTAAAAGGAAGAGGTAGCACTCTTGGTCTGGACATCGAAACAGCCACTCGTGCAGGAAAG
CAGATAGTGGAGCAGATTCTGGAAGAGGAATCAGATGAGGCACTTAAAATGACCATTGCCTCTGTTCCTG
```

Is there a way to skip the title line so I can run analysis on the sequence without separating the title from the sequence completely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just want the substring of the input that starts after the first newline character. That's easy:

```
private static String trimHeader(String input) {
    return input.substring(input.indexOf('\n') + 1);
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, Thank you so much!

Comment: @BrianCheda: I'm glad you found this useful. In the interest of teaching you to fish (as opposed to just giving you a fish): note that my formulation of your question was only slightly differently worded than your original question, and that the code I show is pretty much a literal translation of the problem statement: "the substring of the input that starts (at)" is `String.substring(int)` and "the (location of) the first newline character" is `.indexOf('\n')`, and I turned "(at)" into "after" using `+ 1`. This is a good exercise in learning to *think* in a language. (Really, any language.)

Comment: And, as an exercise for the reader: in what circumstance could this method throw an exception? I see only one, and it's pretty far-fetched. (The obvious failure mode, where the string doesn't contain a newline character, is already handled, although perhaps non-obviously so.)

Answer (score 0):

You can split/tokenize your string by `(NS)` assuming there is a pattern in your title and sequence line

This will give you a sequence of the item

```
String sequence = AI.get(1).split("(NS)")[1]
```